# Voronoi diagram on (weighted) graphs

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, graph-distance

Suppose I have a graph $G$ (possibly with weights on edges), and I have a subset $S$ of $k$ vertices $s_1, \dotsc, s_k$. I want to solve the post office problem: that is, I want to partition the vertices of $G$ into subsets $D_1, \dotsc, D_k,$ so that $s_i$ is the closest vertex of $S$ to every vertex in $D_i.$ I assume this has been studied - what is the most efficient algorithm?

Comment: Add a new root node $r$ connected with $s_1,\ldots,s_k$ with edges of weight $1$, say. Then find a minimum weight spanning tree $T$  with root $r$ using Dijkstra's algorithm, for example. Given any node $n$ the path from $n$ to $r$ in $T$ will lead to the nearest post office at the next to last step.

Comment: Dijkstra on an augmented graph is the right call, but its output is not a minimum weight spanning tree but a [shortest path tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest-path_tree).

Comment: @BenBarber Indeed. For some reason I hadn't heard of the shortest path tree. If you want to make this an answer, I am happy to accept.

Comment: @BenBarber Thanks for the correction! A minimum weight spanning tree would also work, but Dijkstra's algorithm is quick and to the point.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais, I'm not sure that's right: if everywhere is 2 from the root but 1 from each other then a minimum spanning overestimates the distance to almost everywhere.

Comment: @IgorRivin neither had I!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you decide that the elements of $S$ should look for the vertices in their part rather than the other way round the naive approach of exploring edges one at a time in increasing distance from $S$ is the best you can do (up to administrative overhead) because you might have to examine all of the edges anyway.  This is essentially [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).